# WooCommerce Basked Wont Float

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having an issue where I cannot get my WooCommerce store basked to float over a button as shown in the image below

[image showing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XGq7.png)

I have tried assigning position relative to both elements and then using Z-index as well however this has resulted with no success.

Any help would be most appreciated thank you

Comment: Posting an image with no associated code is like emailing an image of your car to the auto repair shop and asking why your car won't start. In short, (almost) impossible to answer without extra details

Comment: @7uc1f3r thank you for  getting back to me sorry for not replying I thought I shut this before anyone responded. I appreciate your feedback and will add the used code next time sorry for this. I did manage to fix the issue by adding a new z-index to the element and then add some padding to position it correctly thank you again for your assistance